# C# regex to split string and include matched expression in split

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have the following string:

```
Bacon ipsum dolor amet **kevin kielbasa** pork chop picanha chuck, 
t-bone **brisket corned beef fatback hamburger cow** sirloin shank prosciutto
shankle. T-bone pancetta ribeye **tongue** fatback drumstick frankfurter short 
ribs burgdoggen. **Tail cupim.**
```

I want to obtain:

```
List<string>(){
    "Bacon ipsum dolor amet ",
    "**kevin kielbasa**",
    " pork chop picanha chuck, t-bone ",
    "**brisket corned beef fatback hamburger cow**",
    " sirloin shank prosciutto shankle. T-bone pancetta ribeye ",
    "**tongue**",
    " fatback drumstick frankfurter short ribs burgdoggen. ",
    "**Tail cupim.**"
}
```

**Approaches:**

1. Entirely in Regex:

*First Pass*

`Regex.Split(str, @"\*\*.*?\*\*");`

```
"Bacon ipsum dolor amet ",
" pork chop picanha chuck, t-bone ",
" sirloin shank prosciutto shankle. T-bone pancetta ribeye ",
" fatback drumstick frankfurter short ribs burgdoggen. "
```

Split *removes* all of the matching items. It treats each one as a delimiter between the items it thinks we want. D'oh!

*Second Pass*

`Regex.Matches(str, @"\*\*.*?\*\*").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();`

```
"**kevin kielbasa**",
"**brisket corned beef fatback hamburger cow**",
"**tongue**",
"**Tail cupim.**"
```

Well, that makes sense. `Regex.Matches()` returns all of the items that match the regular expression, so we've lost all of the content between.

2. With a dash of LINQ:

Okay, let's see if we can get all of our text in a list together:

`Regex.Split(str, @"\*\*");`

```
"Bacon ipsum dolor amet ",
"kevin kielbasa",
" pork chop picanha chuck, t-bone ",
"brisket corned beef fatback hamburger cow",
" sirloin shank prosciutto shankle. T-bone pancetta ribeye ",
"tongue",
" fatback drumstick frankfurter short ribs burgdoggen. ",
"Tail cupim."
```

Oddly, this simple regex gets us the closest, but we no longer know which items in the list were surrounded by `**`s. Because the `**` alternates every list item, all we need to know is if the first (or second) item in the list is surrounded by `**`.

`bool firstIsMatch = "**" == new string(str.Take(2).ToArray());`

And then we can use that bool to determine if we're adding "**" to the beginning and end of every even or odd item in the list.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to do this entirely with a regex? If so, how?
- Despite being "more code", is the second option preferred for performance and/or readability?

Comment: your first attempt but in `()` for it to be included in the results [`Regex.Split(str, @"(\*\*.*?\*\*)");`](https://regex101.com/r/qMj0p9/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to wrap your regex in a capturing group. Once the regex finds the match to split on, the match text will be also pushed into the resulting array. See [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx) reference:

> If capturing parentheses are used in a `Regex.Split` expression, *any captured text is included in the resulting string array*. For example, if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element that contains the hyphen.

The empty elements can be easily filtered out later with LINQ:

```
var str  = "Bacon ipsum dolor amet **kevin kielbasa** pork chop picanha chuck, t-bone **brisket corned beef fatback hamburger cow** sirloin shank prosciutto shankle. T-bone pancetta ribeye **tongue** fatback drumstick frankfurter short ribs burgdoggen. **Tail cupim.**";
var res = Regex.Split(str, @"(\*{2}.*?\*{2})", RegexOptions.Singleline) // Split and keep  the captures
        .Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)); // Remove blank elements
Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"", string.Join("\"\n\"", res));
```

See [C# demo](http://ideone.com/msumRA).

And a small note on the performance of the pattern: if the text is very large, you might experience a slow down due to the lazy dot matching pattern. It is a good idea to unroll it as [`@"\*{2}[^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*\*{2}"`](https://regex101.com/r/gafV2o/1) especially if there is a small amount of "wild", standalone asterisks (the delimiters).

Comment: Worth noting that I chose this answer because of extended description and handling of null/whitespace elements.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Regex.Matches` with pipe in your regex eg

```
(?s)\*\*.*?\*\*|.+?(?=\*\*|$)
```

[See demo at regex storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fs%29%5c*%5c*.*%3f%5c*%5c*%7c.%2b%3f%28%3f%3d%5c*%5c*%7c%24%29&i=Bacon+ipsum+dolor+amet+**kevin+kielbasa**+pork+chop+picanha+chuck%2c+t-bone+**brisket+corned+beef+fatback+hamburger+cow**+sirloin+shank+prosciutto+shankle.+T-bone+pancetta+ribeye+**tongue**+fatback+drumstick+frankfurter+short+ribs+burgdoggen.+**Tail+cupim.**)

The [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in *or-part* to stop right before `**` or `$` end.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
var s = "Bacon ipsum dolor amet **kevin kielbasa** pork chop picanha chuck, " +
"t-bone **brisket corned beef fatback hamburger cow** sirloin shank prosciutto " +
"shankle. T-bone pancetta ribeye **tongue** fatback drumstick frankfurter short " +
"ribs burgdoggen. **Tail cupim.**";

var split = Regex.Split(s, @"(?=\*\*\S)|(?<=\S\*\*)");

foreach (var part in split)
{
    Console.WriteLine(part);
}

// == OUTPUT ==
//
// Bacon ipsum dolor amet 
// **kevin kielbasa**
//  pork chop picanha chuck, t-bone 
// **brisket corned beef fatback hamburger cow**
//  sirloin shank prosciutto shankle. T-bone pancetta ribeye 
// **tongue**
//  fatback drumstick frankfurter short ribs burgdoggen. 
// **Tail cupim.**
```